# How to insert POINT into mysql using gorm?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

```
func (loc Location) GormValue(ctx context.Context, db *gorm.DB) clause.Expr {
    return clause.Expr{
        SQL:  "POINT(?)",
        Vars: []interface{}{fmt.Sprintf("%f, %f", loc.X, loc.Y)},
    }
}
```

This is my valuer. And it creates a query like this `POINT('XX.XXXXX, YY.YYYYY')`. But this query does not work because of single quotation marks. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to use MySQL-specific functions like `GeomFromText` or `PointFromText` to convert the string to spatial data type.

```
func (loc Location) GormValue(ctx context.Context, db *gorm.DB) clause.Expr {
    return clause.Expr{
        SQL:  "PointFromText(?)",
        Vars: []interface{}{fmt.Sprintf("POINT(%f %f)", loc.X, loc.Y)},
    }
}
```

More details are provided [here](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Create-x2F-Update-from-SQL-Expr). Also, please note that based on which version of MySQL you are using, these functions might be named differently. For example, the MySQL 5.6 `PointFromText` function corresponds to MySQL 8.0 `ST_PointFromText` function.